# Node on Windows?

Tags: node

Is there a way to build a full node on a Windows system (not a docker build)?

If not, is there a particular reason why the platform is *not* supported?

Comment: Probably because OCaml (the language of Tezos code) is not supported well on Windows: http://www.ocaml.org/docs/install.html#Windows

Comment: @utdrmac thanks! Will give a look. I am curious if someone ever have it a try.

Comment: Windows OS is not stable, recommended like-Linux OS.

Answer (score 2):

Linux is a much more secure platform than Windows. You can use it to build a node, but I recommend building a node on Linux

Comment: Bitcoin needs as much security as tezos well but there is a windows node. I don’t believe absence of the windows node is a consequence of the team rejecting windows as « unsafe ».

Answer (score 1):

Well, one workaround would be to use the Windows Subsystem for Linux.
But really, using docker is so, so much easier.

Comment: Not for baking i believe ?

Comment: @Ezy why not for baking? I use it for baking, works fine! 

Comment: @asbjornenge did you manage to apply the ledger udev rules and connect it?

Comment: @jdsika well yes, I'm currently baking & using remote signer using docker. But if I remember correctly the issue wasn't the udev rules but some permissions issue - need to run the signer container as privileged and as the root user inside the container or something like that  It's been a while since I set it up 

Comment: You would do me a tremendous favor if you would edit my answer here and extend it with the ledger instructions!

Answer (score 1):

I am using the Windows subsystem and I wanted to write an answer but apparently someone wrote exactly what I had in mind :)
I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on Windows 10 from the Windows Store:

[Enable Ubunut on Windows as described here](https://docs.microsoft.com/de-de/windows/wsl/install-win10)

*Note: WSL is available since [Windows 10 version 2004](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-2004#windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl)*

[Go and see here for troubleshooting if you already tried to init opam](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55001370/2883130)

I am using this on a fresh installation:

```
sh <(curl -sL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ocaml/opam/master/shell/install.sh)
opam init --disable-sandboxing
opam switch create for_tezos 4.09.1
```

[The installation of the Tezos binaries through opam worked great:](http://tezos.gitlab.io/introduction/howtoget.html)

```
opam install depext
opam depext tezos
opam install tezos
```

And update it:

```
opam update
opam depext
opam upgrade
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful!
Just wanted to add that you need Windows 10 version 2004 (https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-2004#windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl)