# Windows Subsystem for Linux 2 - Ubuntu 20.04 LTS - Does it work with Tezos?

Tags: windows, compile

I tried with Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL 1 and it did not work, it was not possible to build from source.

Has anybody tried compiling on WSL2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This comment by user jdsika includes all the steps needed to run Tezos on WSL2.

https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/2801/1785

Note that Windows 10 version 2004 is needed. https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/whats-new/whats-new-windows-10-version-2004#windows-subsystem-for-linux-wsl

Answer (score 2):

I was able to make it work, you need to disable `bubblewrap` which is used by opam but not supported in WSL. You can do so using the `--disable-sandboxing` flag.

See https://github.com/ocaml/opam-repository/issues/12050#issuecomment-393478072

Comment: Unfortunately, after building, I get this issue https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/1005/error-in-alphanet-mdb-corrupted-located-page-was-wrong-type

Comment: See https://gitlab.com/tezos/tezos/-/issues/229

Comment: I don't see any solution TBH. I'm using v7.1 which should not be using LMDB

Comment: Can you open a ticket on gitlab?